# how limit number message in storm?

Tags: apache-storm

I programming on project that need limit message process on whole storm. spout read message from ActiveMQ and I save message not ack to hashmap with ID and when hashmap size reach the limit, I won't read from ActiveMQ until size of hashmap reach under limit. The problem is I need final bolts ack in spout, In other word, the bolts receive message from spout when ack to spout that them recieve ack from next bolt.How Implement that? how detect bolts receive ack?

Comment: Can you just confirm what you are asking? So you want to buffer messages in a HashMap in your spout and send them to the rest of the topology, to the bolts, and remove them from the HashMap only when they are acked? You want to stop fetching messages when the HashMap is full? You also want the final bolt to ack them and then propagate that ack back to the spout?

Comment: I remove message from HashMap when next bolt ack back to spout but I want remove message when final bolt ack back to spout. I want final bolt ack back to the spout.